# How do I work out ${10\sqrt 30}\over{ 5\sqrt5}$ $?$

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, radicals

I am told the answer is $10\sqrt 6$ but I keep getting $2\sqrt 6$. How do I get $10\sqrt6$ as the answer$?$

Comment: 2sqrt6 is right.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the order of the operations. The way you phrased it I'd say $2\sqrt{6}$ is correct.

$$10\cdot \sqrt{30} / (5\cdot \sqrt{5})=2\sqrt{6}$$
$$10\cdot\sqrt{30}/5\cdot \sqrt{5}=10\sqrt{6}$$